# How to pass arguments depending on columns when using R dplyr's summarise_each( ) function

Tags: r, arguments, dplyr

for a data.frame containing multiple columns, I am planning to compute each column's data percentage beyond [low, high] range. Since such "low" and "high" values vary across the columns (computed as pcts in the below code piece), how can I pass each column's corresponding "low" and "high" values when using summarise_each() function? So far, I can only input the fixed values as shown in the sample.

```
pct10 <- function(dbl){quantile(dbl, 0.1)}
pct90 <- function(dbl){quantile(dbl, 0.9)}

valid.fms <- headgaze %>%
          filter(tracking_status == "OK")

pcts <- valid.fms %>%
     summarise_each(funs(pct10, pct90),
             head_pitch, head_yaw, head_roll,
             gaze_x, gaze_y, gaze_z)

 extreme.rt <- function(dbl, low, high){
               length(dbl[dbl < low | dbl > high])/length(dbl)

  }

feats <- valid.fms %>%
      group_by(lab_session) %>%
      summarise_each(funs(extreme.rt(., -10.98332, 11.045)),
                head_pitch, head_yaw, head_roll)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution yet ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that general solution exists (cause you need to pass list alike object to `summarise_each`).
But for your case some changes can help. First mark which is beyond range, then count it. You could achieve this using `mutate_each`:

```
is_beyond <- function(x) x < pct10(x) | x > pct90(x)
headgaze %>%
    filter(tracking_status == "OK") %>%
    mutate_each(
        funs(is_beyond)
        ,head_pitch, head_yaw, head_roll, gaze_x, gaze_y, gaze_z
    ) %>%
    group_by(lab_session) %>% # ! this comes *after* mutate
    summarise_each(funs(mean), head_pitch, head_yaw, head_roll, gaze_x, gaze_y, gaze_z)
```